# Java giving NoClassDefFoundError when importing maven package

Tags: java, maven

I have a simple java code, `App.java`. I am trying to import the apache commons Fraction class from the apache commons math3 library. So, as a sample code, I put this in my `App.java`:

```
package myApp;
import org.apache.commons.math3.fraction.Fraction;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Fraction f = new Fraction(2, 3);
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        System.out.println( f );
    }
}
```

Using the following POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>myApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>Proj1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Proj1</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.4</version>
          <configuration>
            <!-- put your configurations here -->
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have tried to put the plugin suggested by [utdemir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472416/utdemir) in his answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency), but in my case, when I run:

```java
mvn package
java -cp target/Proj1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar myApp.App
```

While it apparently compiles properly, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/fraction/Fraction
        at myApp.App.main(App.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.fraction.Fraction
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 1 more
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are any of these answers helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673427/noclassdeffounderror-with-apache-commons-math

Comment: They all mention that we need to add a JAR file somewhere. Is there any way for Maven to add the jar automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its much easier to run your app using `mvn`, rathen than by calling `java` directly. This is because in the later case you need to manually set the classpath to the correct value using the `-cp` flag. This can lead to errors, like in your case.

Here's how you can run your app using `mvn`

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="myApp.App"
```

More details can be found [here](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/)

Comment: This is it! I was also looking for a way to use maven to automatically download any additional dependencies. The exec command does exactly that. Thank you!